# Asphalt 8 multiplayer rating

Tags: asphalt-8

I have a problem with Asphalt 8. Multiple times when I get third, my rating goes down by 10. When you get third in pro league or higher, your rating is supposed to stay equal if you get third. But instead of my rating staying equal, it goes down by ten and the person who leaves has their rating increase. And for some reason, my rating decreases when it should stay equal if I get third. Does anyone know why this glitch is happening?

Comment: This may be intended behaviour. Odd, but oh well.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/Asphalt8/comments/hpt8ku/multiplayer_rating_criteria/), you are experiencing a difference in points depending on whether your opponent was of higher or lower **rank** than you are.

> Depends on how high or low ranked your opponents are. If they're significantly higher than you and you actually beat them, you earn a lot of points but if you lose to them, you might not lose or gain much depending on how bad the loss is.
> If you're beating lower ranked players, you won't get much but if you lose to them, you'll lose a lot of points.

Thus, in the matches where you got third place but your rating went down, it was likely that you lost to a significantly lower ranked opponent. As a result, your score went down.